# Is it possible to cook a meatloaf using clear glass Pyrex containers?

Tags: baking, equipment, meat

Still trying to restock my kitchen pans after my recent move and am on a budget, but what I do have is as set of clear pyrex, that looks about like this set: [http://www.amazon.com/Pyrex-6021224-Storage-10-Piece-Clear/dp/B00005B8K5/ref=sr_1_1?s=gateway&ie=UTF8&qid=1285775513&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005B8K5)

My question is can I use it to cook a meatloaf? If I cannot use it to cook a meatloaf then have you ever cooked a meatloaf on a cookie sheet without it falling to pieces and/or burning on the bottom?

Comment: Are you concerned with the fact that these are glass, or that they're shallow pans?

Comment: I was more concerned with the temperature and shattering glass and meatloaf shrapnel. :)

Comment: as far as I know, there's very little difference between glass Pyrex storage and glass Pyrex baking dishes.

Comment: Pyrex bakeware may be one of two things: borosilicate glass or tempered glass. Storage will be either tempered or plain glass. Borosilicate is the most thermal-shock resistant; plain glass the least. Tempered should be fine for baking, as long as you don't (for example) take it out of the oven then toss it on a cold, wet surface. Put it on heat pads instead.

Comment: As an alternate to a cookie sheet, I'd recommend a broiler pan, if you have one;  that way, any extra grease will drop away, and be contained underneath.  The pan's generally a little deeper than a cooke sheet, so you won't have as high of a risk of sloshing hot grease on you when you go to remove it from the oven.

Comment: related http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17970/is-pyrex-safe-to-use-on-a-gas-burner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see no reason you couldn't use that Pyrex set for a meatloaf - I've used glass casseroles for meatloaf before (so glass in general is no problem), and that set says the bowls are oven safe.

As for the cookie sheet method, I would be afraid of it falling apart as you described, but if you were to go that route, I'd recommend wrapping it in aluminum foil to help it keep its shape.

Comment: When baking with a glass dish, you may want to lower the temperature 25 degrees, as glass dishes conduct heat better than light metal pans.  Other than that, you should be totally fine.

Comment: And remember to bake it without the plastic tops—use foil if your recipe recommends covering.

Comment: I have never had a meatloaf fall apart on me, and nine times out of ten I bake it freeform on a cookie sheet. Try Alton Brown's recipe, as it is optimized for this method. I would also advise putting a large pan under the sheet to catch drippings.

Comment: I have always preferred to use glass baking dishes as I think they clean up much easier. So all my meatloaves were made in a glass dish. I form it smaller than the dish (sort of mounded in the center) so the liquid has somewhere to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably long-resolved for the OP, but to any other Pyrex owners out there: I had a few of the blue glass-looking ones several years ago. Someone gave them to me, so no clue on the price point or any descriptive sub-names.

Thinking they were like my beloved but lost old-school Corningware®, I browned two big thick rib pork chops in one on the stove burner before putting it in the oven, at about 350F. Not 20 minutes in they shattered all over the oven and yes, saturated the chops and their stuffing with bright blue shrapnel.

Comment: The glass is not made for direct or really high heat, so the issue was putting it directly on the cook top. Any time you know you need to use the cook top, ALWAYS use a metal dish of some kind.