# Are Pyrex casserole dishes safe for use on electric stovetops?

Tags: cookware, electric-stoves, kitchen-safety

Would it be okay if a Pyrex baking dish is used on an electric stove top to reheat food?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17970/is-pyrex-safe-to-use-on-a-gas-burner/, stovetop is the same or even worse than a gas burner in this case.

Answer (score 26):

NO! It would not. They will break, possibly violently. Unless they are labeled for that use, don't do it.

Answer (score 12):

No, this is a very, very bad idea.  The thermal gradient can lead to uneven expansion and shattering.

This is true of the modern product as well as the historical borosilicate product.

Answer (score 4):

The only Pyrex that I'm aware of that was labeled as being safe for the cooktop was the 'Pyrex Visions' line, and I don't believe they ever made anything that I'd call a 'baking dish' from it.  I know they made skillets, pots, and dutch ovens, and the associated lids.

It's typically a sort of orange-brown color, and there were also some pink-ish ones.

There's also Pyrex that's used for science labs ... again, not casserole dishes, but many are rated for thermal stress, as they make various weights (price vs. durability)

Answer (score 3):

The Pyrex company markets a ceramic product called [Pyroflam](http://www.arc-international-cookware.com/en/products/pyroflam) in Europe which can be used on the stove top. This is an opaque material different from the traditional glass products.

Answer (score 1):

NO! Mine too exploded on top of my stove, just last night to be exact. That's why I was looking this up. I had it sitting there and turned on the wrong burner and it went everywhere. It was really loud and chunks of glass everywhere, took me an hour to clean up

Answer (score 0):

NO Mine exploded on top of my stove. I had it sitting there and turned wrong burner on and it went everywhere. It was really loud.!!But I will buy another one.