# How to reduce a sauce at the bottom of a baking dish?

Tags: stove, electric-stoves, reduction

A recipe I'm interested in making asks to bake some vegetables in the oven in a baking dish, afterwards, to reduce any remaining liquid by putting the pan on a stove over medium heat.

I'm not sure whether it's safe to put a baking dish onto a stove, and since I have a glass-topped electric stove I'm worried that doing this will cause the dish to break due to uneven heating.

Is it safe to place the dish there? If not, how would I go about reducing any liquid left at the bottom of the dish?

Thanks!

Comment: *All* stoves risk breaking ceramic bakeware (pyrex, casserole dishes, etc.).  You're better off pouring the liquid into a pan that's better shaped for the stove, anyway.

Comment: Surely it means a metal baking pan??

Comment: @Jefromi I hope so! The recipe doesn't actually specify. Could I use an oven-safe pan for this?

Comment: Where "oven-safe" = "metal", then yes.

Comment: Though I wouldn't recommend trying this with an electric stove, I deglaze baking dishes all the time with a gas stove, never broke any baking dish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WOW...this is a published recipe?? [Are Pyrex casserole dishes safe for use on electric stovetops?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39611/are-pyrex-casserole-dishes-safe-for-use-on-electric-stovetops/39613#39613)  It is very dangerous to put most bakeware on most stoves. Your best option would be to either originally bake in a stove-safe implement, or to transfer from a casserole to a saucepan at that point.

Only, only use cookware labeled as safe for a stove (usually only metal) on a stove! Period! To do otherwise as asking for potentially deadly shrapnel. I am not kidding!

Comment: The recipe comes from Thomas Keller of The French Laundry, so I assume it's safe. :-) 

Would it potentially be safe, for example, to bake in something like an ovenproof pan and then put that directly on the stove?

Comment: Ovenproof=/=stoveproof! If the pan is made for use on the stove, then you're fine. But not all pans made for the stove can be used in the oven either. Some handles will melt, but at least that won't cause flying shrapnel.

Comment: I would add if you need to deglaze a Pyrex baking dish, let it cool down a bit, pour HOT water in it, and then just use some elbow grease to scrape up the rosted bits.  To reduce the liquid, pour it into a regular stove-top pan and finish.  I am always careful where glass is involved.